# C# - Dsharp: How to edit a message sent by the bot

Tags: c#, .net, dsharp+

How can I edit a message that the bot sent using message's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has very little context, so it's difficult to say what you're doing. But a quick search through the project's [issue tracking](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus/issues) led me to [this post](https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus/issues/620), which indicates you basically just call `ModifyAsync` on the message:

```
await botMessage.ModifyAsync("New content", newEmbed);
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I find the message with the ID and save it in a variable?

Comment: @Nedd You'll have to provide some code to show what it is you're doing before I can help you any further. As you can see people are downvoting the question - probably because there's no information about the context of your question.